# Allow users to run existing version of clickonce app when update fails

Tags: clickonce, mage

I am working on a ClickOnce application, and deploying using Mage.

Is there a way to allow users to run their installed version of the application if an update fails? Some users are occasionaly unable to run the program when connecting to the internet via a proxy (eg. wireless hotspots in hotels, coffee shops etc.).

I know that it is possible to use the -MinVersion argument to Mage to allow users to skip an update entirely, but we have had issues in the past with users *never* updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options. First, you could have ClickOnce check for updates *after* the application starts rather than before. The one downside with the approach is that users don't get the update until they restart the application.

Another option would be to stop ClickOnce from automaticallly checking for updates and [do it programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404263.aspx). This way you're in complete control of when update checks happen, what to do if they fail, forcing the user to restart the app, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but there is no way to do this unless you have them install the application from a different URL, but if they can do that, they can just invoke the update by reinstalling the applcation from the original URL.

The version of the application that the user is running is determined by the deployment manifest (.application file) in the root of the deployment directory on the server. So if you have version 1.0.0.4 in that folder, the user will get 1.0.0.4.

If you are doing required updates (min version) and want to revert to 1.0.0.3, you can copy the deployment manifest from the 1_0_0_3 versioned folder under Application Files and put it in the root folder, but they will still have to uninstall and reinstall because of the minimum version being set.